# Is any way to generate a multiplataform exe/executable from a python file?

Tags: python, exe

I want to convert a .py file into a multiplataform (Windows, Linux,..) onefile (without librarys or other folders) executable file for using it without a Python installation.

Comment: use `py2exe` or `pyinstaller`

Comment: Uh, windows executables are different from linux executables. So no.

Comment: with py2exe you can generate onefile executable? I tryed to install pyinstaller with pip install pyinstaller but throws errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyInstaller has the option to create a one-file application, just use the "-F" or "--onefile" argument when using it. I have never tried it on Linux though, on Windows I think it works.

[PyInstaller Documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) at "What to generate"

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it

Comment: You're welcome, make sure to report afterwards.

Comment: I did with the pyinstaller. First, I tryed pyinstaller -F program_name.py but it didn´t work. I put the -Fw parameter to see the errors (F:one file, w: show in prompt) and i saw that some librarys were not included into the exe. For that, i used the -hidden-import=library_name parameter. So, finally i used this: pynstaller -F --hidden-import=libray_name1 --hidden-import=libray_name2... script_name.py